# Rails Highstock Chart Installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I am fairly new to RoR and completely new to Javascript.  I would like to simply set up the Highstock chart but cant seem to get even remotely close, I've restarted over 4 times and still no progress.  I cant seem to decipher the documentation (even though it isnt too clear for newbs) can anyone help me get started?

Comment: Please check [rCharts](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/blob/master/inst/libraries/highcharts/examples.R) kind of wrapper of highcharts for rails.

Comment: I'm interested in the highstock chart not the regular charts

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/ankit8898/highstocks-rails by ankit8898 this gem supports Supports both **highstocks** and **highcharts**  I would still take a look at the ['lazy_high_charts' gem](https://github.com/michelson/lazy_high_charts)  for how eassy it is to set up  and use.

Comment: You're answering all my questions! Thanks! I'll try it soon and update you (trying to focus on the stripe integration before moving on)